# Dynamically Generate hreflang Tags in WordPress from Language Selector Links Using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual, elementor

I have a WordPress website built with Elementor Pro and I've added a custom HTML language selector at the end of each page. The selector has links to different language versions of the current page. For SEO purposes, I want to dynamically generate hreflang tags in the  section based on these links.

Language Selector HTML example:

```
<div class="lang-popup">
  <div class="lang-selector">
    <div id="langs">
      <a id="lang-item-1" class="lang-item" href="https://example.com/en/page1/">
        <span class="lang-text">English</span>
      </a>
      <a id="lang-item-2" class="lang-item" href="https://example.com/de/seite1/">
        <span class="lang-text">Deutsch</span>
      </a>
      <a id="lang-item-3" class="lang-item" href="https://example.com/ar/صفحة1/">
        <span class="lang-text">عربي</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to write PHP code to pull these URLs from the language selector and generate hreflang tags, but haven't been able to make it work. My goal is to place this code in the header.php file so that it runs dynamically for each page.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
<?php
// Dynamically determine the base URL for the current page
$current_url = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Define the URLs for each language version
$languages = array(
    'en' => str_replace(array('/de/', '/ar/'), '', $current_url),
    'de' => str_replace('/ar/', '/de/', str_replace(array('/de/', '/ar/'), '', $current_url)),
    'ar' => str_replace('/de/', '/ar/', str_replace(array('/de/', '/ar/'), '', $current_url))
);

// Loop through each language and output the hreflang link element
foreach($languages as $lang => $url) {
    echo '<link rel="alternate" hreflang="'.$lang.'" href="'.$url.'">' . "\n";
}

// Output the x-default link element
echo '<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="' . $languages['en'] . '">' . "\n";
?>
```

I can not get the links from my language selector in this code.

I appreciate any guidance on how to best approach this issue.

I want to dynamically generate hreflang tags in the  section based on these links.

I tried to write PHP code to pull these URLs from the language selector and generate hreflang tags, but haven't been able to make it work. My goal is to place this code in the header.php file so that it runs dynamically for each page.

In the end, I can not get the links from my language selector in this code.

Answer (score 0):

In your `header.php`, you can use JavaScript to retrieve and parse the language selector links and generate the `hreflang` tags dynamically.

Ensure that the language links in your language selector have the `hreflang` attribute (e.g., `hreflang="en"`, `hreflang="de"`, etc.) to match the desired language codes for `hreflang` tags.

It should work with Elementor Pro.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Get the language selector links
        const langLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".lang-selector .lang-item");

        // Initialize an empty object to store language URLs
        const languageUrls = {};

        // Loop through the language links and extract the language and URL
        langLinks.forEach(link => {
            const lang = link.getAttribute("hreflang");
            const url = link.getAttribute("href");
            languageUrls[lang] = url;
        });

        // Create and append hreflang tags to the head of the document
        Object.keys(languageUrls).forEach(lang => {
            const hreflangTag = document.createElement("link");
            hreflangTag.setAttribute("rel", "alternate");
            hreflangTag.setAttribute("hreflang", lang);
            hreflangTag.setAttribute("href", languageUrls[lang]);
            document.head.appendChild(hreflangTag);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Note** - Clear any caching mechanisms if you have them in place to see the changes.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but my goal is to write a code that will find the target links of different languages through the "Language Selector", which is different on each page, and assign it to that page as "hreflang".

Comment: Oh I see, I have updated the solution, can you try this one!